# SQLite not creating DateTime field

Tags: c#, sqlite, win-universal-app

In my C# VS2015 Windows 10 Universal App, I cannot create a DateTime field in the database schema. It creates a bigint instead. I have other tables that have created a DateTime field with no problems.

Here is one example: (see the GameDate field)

Table [Results]
    Fields: 17
        [Season]: nvarchar(100)
        [Id]: INTEGER
        [HomeTeamName]: nvarchar(100)
        [OppTeamName]: nvarchar(100)
        [GameDate]: datetime

```
Foreign Keys: 0
Indexes: 1
    [] PRIMARY
        [Id] AUTOINCREMENT 
Triggers: 0
Unique constraints: 0
Check constraints: 0



    private void AddUserButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        User user = new User();
        user.Name = "User1";
        user.GameDate = Convert.ToDateTime("2015-09-02");
        var path = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "BaseBallOU.db");
        using (SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection(new SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(), path))
        {
            conn.Insert(user);
        }
    }

    private void CreateTablesButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var path = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "BaseBallOU.db");
        using (SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection(new SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(), path))
        {
            conn.CreateTable<User>();
            conn.CreateTable<TeamX>();
        }
    }
}
public class User
{

    [SQLite.AutoIncrement, SQLite.PrimaryKey]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public DateTime GameDate { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

}

public class TeamX
{
    [SQLite.AutoIncrement, SQLite.PrimaryKey]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string TeamName { get; set; }
    public DateTime GameDate { get; set; }
}
```

Below is what gets created in the tables:

```
Table [TeamX]
Fields: 3
    [id]: integer
    [TeamName]: varchar
    [GameDate]: bigint
Foreign Keys: 0
Indexes: 0
Triggers: 0
Unique constraints: 0
Check constraints: 0
```

I'm using the following references:

sqlite-net-pcl
SQLite.Net-PCL
SQLite for Universal App Platform

Comment: Miiite, I've seen other references that SQLite does not have a DateTime Datatype but I have other tables that when the schema is evaluated it shows  a "datatime" type.  See the schema for another table below and check out the "GameDate" field.Table  [Results]
    Fields: 17
        [Season]: nvarchar(100)
         [OverUnderTotal]: double precision
        [OverUnderAlpha]: nvarchar(100)
        [GameTotal]: int
        [Id]: INTEGER
        [HomeTeamName]: nvarchar(100)
        [OppTeamName]: nvarchar(100)
        [GameDate]: datetime

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not mistaking, there is no datetime types in SQLite databases.
Convert your date to a string when you save a new object, and convert it back to a DateTime when you read one.

Comment: That's right - see sec 2.2 in the docs for reference - https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html